# Message not addressed to me arrived in MY inbox

Tags: support, comments

Mari-Lou wrote a pugnacious message to persons unknown, did *not* use my @name, but it nevertheless arrived in MY inbox, causing distress.

I suspect a bug.

Comment: Was it a comment (responding to someone else's comment) on one of your questions/answers? That would do it.

Comment: @TimLymington: No, it wasn't. Although a newbie, I know that much. OP was Wapiti, Answerr was Mari-Lou, commenters were me (first), Mari-Lou and Wapiti. With her aggressive message,  Mari-Lou was indignantly addressing persons unknown. But I got the stick, as I said. I was quite upset, though ML and I are good now.

Comment: @DavidPugh Most likely the nametag autocomplete system misfired, causing ML to @-address you in error, immediately generating an notification in your inbox; soon after, ML likely noticed the typo and edited it out of the comment, so by the time you clicked through the alert, the comment bore no trace of your name. Happens to me sometimes. Also: ML has never been pugnacious in my experience. In fact, relatively speaking, she's a model of restrain and tolerance here on SE.

Comment: @Dan: of course I agree with you, she is my favourite person here, though you're pretty positive yourself. But she did put the boot into persons unknown this time. OK, your tag misfire theory sounds credible. It was just something of a perfect storm for me.

Comment: This is almost certainly not a bug, so I'm removing that tag. The @-system WORKS. If you want to yell Bug, you do have to provide links and evidence of a bug.

Comment: @Andrew. Funny, I thought I'd recently removed the Bug tag myself. Perhaps I did it wrong. I ask pardon on grounds of emotional distress.